# i mounted my hardisk partision while instalation

Tags: mount, hard-drive, unmount

while installing Ubuntu 16 i chained the partition settings in that i mounted an hard disk partition with password i want to unmount it please help me to solve this problem this blocked partition is not working even in windows help me to get back that hard disk space.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you did in order to mount "an hard disk partition with password".

Comment: while installing ->try Ubuntu without installing ->install Ubuntu 16.04 -> install menu opens->English->install third-pray->something else->(in that i selected change and i selected some icon below after that create password security came in that i gave password and verified it and gave OK after that that partition is notified as unknown later i selected another partition and  installed Ubuntu   ) After this partition is dispirited

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand a word of what you wrote. And any new information should be added to the question by editing, not just comments.